# Is there a code golf for code efficiency (speed) instead of bytes?

Tags: feature-request

Question in the title. Is there a code golf for code efficiency (speed) instead of bytes?

Comment: [tag:fastest-code]

Answer (score 5):

If you mean speed in terms of run time, [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code).

If you mean efficiency in terms of time complexity, [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm).